# Retrofit 2 - Get request url, on timeout

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I know how I can get the request url on a successful or failed network call:

```
response.raw().request().url()
```

However, if the end point times out I don't get any response, and the call throws a `SocketTimeoutException`

Is there any way to get the request data on timeout from...anything?

The `SocketTimeoutException` only has a stacktrace with multiple `okhttp3`, `okio`, and `retrofit2` elements as string, but nothing really obviously readable.

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want it in logcat you can add a logging interceptor.

Comment: thanks, but no. im looking to keep the data as variables, and pass them around to output them to an analytic server. I might just have to do it by adding a custom interceptor. Thanks anyways.